# Setting non-serializable attribute value into HttpSession

Tags: java, jsf, glassfish-4, serializable, httpsession

I get an error sometimes when I deployed project, but does not it every time. Localbean does not work when the error

error message

```
Warning:   JSF1063: WARNING! Setting non-serializable attribute value into HttpSession (key: localBean, value class: LocalBean).
```

Localbean

```
package com.mycompany.crm;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Locale;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped

public class LocalBean implements Serializable{
    public Locale locale;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        locale = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale();
    }

    public Locale getLocale() {
        return locale;
    }

    public String getLanguage() {
        return locale.getLanguage();
    }

    public void setLanguage(String language) {
        locale = new Locale(language);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().setLocale(locale);
    }
}
```

Comment: change your log settings to DEBUG. I bet the cause is something else, glassfish is probably reporting the wrong error message for you

Comment: how can I change log settings to DEBUG?

Comment: Did you solve that problem in between?

Answer (score 0):

try placing a serialVersionUID field in your class like:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = -1;
```

Comment: Your class seems to be ok, it should be serializable, is there anything else in the logs that shows an Exception? Is LocalBean a property in some other class?

Comment: There is also such an error message,  JSF1074: Managed bean named 'localBean' has already been registered.  Replacing existing managed bean class type com.mycompany.crm.LocalBean with LocalBean.

Comment: perhaps you're mapping your bean twice, try searching on your code for another bean named localBean or change your bean name like @ManagedBean(name="myLocalBean")